# Länderadjektive

Tags: etymology, standard-german, adjective-ending, proper-noun

Servus miteinander,

könnte mir jemand bitte erklären, wie die adjektive der Länder bestimmt werden? Gibt es eine Regel dazu?

Beispiele:

Eng**land** > eng**lisch**

Ir**land** > ir**isch**

... aber ...

Nieder**lande** > nieder**ländisch**

Is**land** > is**ländisch**

Warum heißt es z.B. russisch und nicht russländisch oder deutsch und nicht deutschländisch?

Ich wäre euch für eure Hilfe sehr dankbar!

Und falls es einen Artikel zu dem Thema gibt, bitte den Link dazu teilen.

Mit freundlichen Grüßen

Irendur

Comment: Vielleicht ist es hilfreich, der Frage eine Liste aller Länder, deren Namen auf _-land_ enden, beizufügen: Deutschland ("deutsch"), England ("englisch"), Estland ("estnisch" [!]), Finnland ("finnisch"), Griechenland ("griechisch"), Grönland ("grönländisch"), Irland ("irisch"), Island ("isländisch"), Lettland ("lettisch"), Niederlande ("niederländisch"), Russland ("russisch"), Schottland ("schottisch"), Thailand (die Sprache heißt "Thai", das Länderadjektiv "thailändisch")

Comment: Die vollständige Liste des Auswärtigen Amtes gib es [hier](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/blob/215256/329771379c1c045ecd02eed3e3667df0/laenderverzeichnis-data.pdf). Trotz weniger, weit verbreiteter Muster sehe ich keine Alternative zum Nachschlagen.

Comment: Ich gebe zu bedenken, dass es das Wort *»deutschländisch«* sehr wohl gibt: [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/deutschländisch), [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/deutschlaendisch). Es wird verwendet um einen ausdrücklichen Bezug zum Staat Deutschland herzustellen, denn das Wort *»deutsch«* könnte auch als *»deutschsprachig«* verstanden werden, was man in manchen Fällen explizit ausschließen will. (Meint man mit *"Goethe ist der größte deutscher Dichter"* ob er der größte Dichter Deutschlands oder der größte deutschsprachige Dichter ist?)

Comment: Niederlande würde zu *niedrig*, oder? Niederisch?

Comment: Stil-Anmerkung zu "Servus" und "Mit freundlichen Grüßen": "Servus" ist informell und regionaltypisch für den Süden, "mit freundlichen Grüßen" ist formell, typisch für den geschäftlichen Briefverkehr, also passen beide nicht gut zusammen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe leider keinen Artikel gefunden, kann aber den Unterschied erklären:

**Manche Bezeichnungen basieren auf dem Namen des Landes, andere auf dem Namen der dort lebenden Menschen.**

**Hier ist die Etymologie Menschen ->  Land & Adjektiv**

| Menschen | Land | Adjektiv | Bemerkung |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deutsche | Deutschland | deutsch |  |
| [Angeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angeln_(Volk)) | England | englisch | mittlerweile Engländer |
| Esten | Estland | estnisch | Woher das n kommt weiß ich nicht |
| Finnen | Finnland | finnisch |  |
| Friesen | Friesland | friesisch |  |
| Griechen | Griechenland | griechisch |  |
| Iren | Irland | irisch | selten Irländer |
| Letten | Lettland | lettisch |  |
| [Rus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rus_(Volk))(sen) | Russland | russisch |  |
| Schotten | Schottland | Schottisch |  |

**Hier ist die Etymologie Land -> Menschen & Adjektiv**

| Land | Menschen | Adjektiv | Bemerkung |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Burgenland | Burgenländer | burgenländisch | Benannt nach drei "[-Burgen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgenland#Name)" |
| Grönland | Grönländer | grönländisch | "Grün-Land" |
| Island | Isländer | isländisch | "Eis-Land" |
| Niederlande | Niederländer | niederländisch | "Niedrige Länder"/Territorien |
| Saarland | Saarländer | saarländisch | Land an der Saar |
| Seeland | Seeländer | seeländisch | Land an der See |

Die Niederlande heißen so, weil sie die niedrig liegenden Territorien der Burgunder und Habsburger waren. Island ist das Land des Eises. Dort sind die Menschen nach dem Land benannt. Beide Länder wurden benannt, bevor es eine nationale Identität gab, nach der sie hätten benannt werden können.

**Hier ist es kompliziert**

| Land | Menschen | Adjektiv | Bemerkung |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frankreich | Franzosen | französisch | lat. Franci |
| Rheinland | Rheinländer | rheinländisch, **rheinisch** | Land am Rhein |
| Thailand | Thailänder | thailändisch | "Thai" bezeichnet eine spezielle Volksgruppe, nicht aber die gesamte Bevölkerung des Landes. 1939 wurde Siam zu Thailand umbenannt, was einen Einfluss gehabt haben könnte |
| Swasiland (heute Eswatini) | Swasi | Swasiländisch | Hier könnte es auch interessante Vermischungen zwischen Land und Ethnie geben, über die ich aber leider nichts weiß |

Ein ähnliches Konstrukt wie in Thailand gibt es auch für andere Länder. Estländer, Finnländer, Friesländer und Schottländer existieren als Einwohnerbezeichnungen und werden benutzt, um die Einwohner des Landes von den Angehörigen der Volksgruppe zu unterscheiden (Finnländer sind beispielsweise explizit schwedischsprachige Einwohner Finnlands). Eventuell ist das auch die Herkunft von "Engländer", da die Angeln in die Angelsachsen aufgegangen sind und England zusätzlich durch viele andere Gruppen besiedelt wurde.